# Grails +ReactJS. How to render the contents of an array given the ID number

Tags: reactjs, grails

So I have a project where users can click on events in our application and see various information about it. On this event page, there will be a comment section where they will be able to see comments already posted as well as creating their own comments. I am having trouble with parsing through the array of comments and rendering them onto the page. Here is what I currently have

This is the react.js class that I'm using to render the page

```js
    render() {
       
        let comments = this.state.event_comments.map( (comment) => {
            return <div className="main">
                <p>{comment.id} </p>
            </div>
        });

        return (

            <div className="main">
          

                    <h2> Comments: </h2> <br/>
                    {comments}

                    <br/>

                    <CommentForm submitLabel="Post Comment" onSubmit={this.update_comments} ref={ (ref) => this.form = ref }/>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(EventPage);
```

This is the Event Domain class

```js
package grails3.example

class Event {

    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]

    static belongsTo = [creator: User, attendees: User]

    static constraints = {
        description nullable: true
     
    }

    String name
    String description
    

}
```

This is the controller for the event class

```js
def update_comments(@RequestParameter('q') String q, @RequestParameter('c') String c){
    def target_event = Event.findByEventbrite_id(q)
    def newComment = new Comment()
    newComment.comment_body = c
    target_event.addToComments(newComment)

    // save to database, print errors for debugging if unable to save
    if(!target_event.save(flush:true) ) {
        System.out.println(target_event.errors)
    }

    respond target_event
}
```

So each event has many comments associated with it, so I stored it into an array in the react.js file and I am trying to get the comment_body to render but it only gives me the comment ID and is not rendering the comments themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly best course of action is to put a debugger here and see what this.state.event_comments actually is composed of.

```
    let comments = this.state.event_comments.map( (comment) => {
        debugger
        return <div className="main">
            <p>{comment.id} </p>
        </div>
    });
```

My feeling is you have object or some other type in your array.